# Apache returns sitemap.xml not /sitemap

Tags: xml, apache, mod-rewrite

First, this problem is on my local testing site; the live site is okay.

I have a site where there is a link to blah.com/sitemap. In the DocRoot there is a file called sitemap.xml, which I don't want to display in response to that link. There is a rewrite rule in /.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule "^([a-z]{1}[\w_\-]+[a-z]{1})$" "/index.php?action=$1" [L]
```

So, /sitemap should be rewritten to index.php?action=sitemap. The rewrite rule works for everything else on the site.

I presume there is an apache configuration difference between the live and local sites, but I've exhausted my ideas for what it might be. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This shoud be placed on superuser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior can be caused by [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot. It was activated in the userdir.conf, which is certainly a difference from the usage with the live set-up. Mucho thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Almost no idea this caused by MultiViews.